# How can I get the text inside the element inside another element by custom attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I am trying to get the text of an element by his parent attribute (data-id) with JQuery, however, I am not able to get it.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```js
function getNum() {
  return "1234asd";
}

function show() {
  console.log($("tr[data-id="+getNum()+"] > td > label").text());
  //Console should print "Text1"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr data-id="1234asd">
    <td>
      <label>Text1</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>Text2</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-id="5678fgh">
    <td>
      <label>Text3</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>Text4</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onClick="show()">Click me</button>
```

I am expecting the code to print `Text1` but it's printing nothing (an empty string).

Comment: That is invalid html.

Comment: @NenadVracar I did not write the whole table to keep it simple, it should work anyways.

Comment: `$("tr[data-id='1234asd']").find("td:first label")`
This will work for your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you can use the approach as mentioned by [Deepak Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55807002/how-can-i-get-text-inside-element-inside-another-element-by-custom-attribute-it#comment98281807_55807002) or you can use the  [`.first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/) of JQuery

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr data-id="1234asd">
        <td>
            <label>Text1</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>Text2</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button onClick="show()">Click me</button>
```

JS

```
function getNum() {
  return "1234asd";
}

function show() {
  console.log($("tr[data-id="+getNum()+"] td").first().text());
  //Console prints "Text1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust your selector, it could be like :

```
$("tr[data-id="+getNum()+"] td:first label").text()
```

```js
function getNum() {
  return "1234asd";
}

function show() {
  console.log($("tr[data-id=" + getNum() + "] td:first label").text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr data-id="1234asd">
    <td>
      <label>Text1</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>Text2</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-id="5678fgh">
    <td>
      <label>Text3</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>Text4</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onClick="show()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function getNum() {
  return "1234asd";
}

function show() {
  console.log($("tr[data-id="+getNum()+"] > td > label").text());
  //Console should print "Text1"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr data-id="1234asd">
  <td>
    <label>Text1</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <label>Text2</label>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
<button onClick="show()">Click me</button>
```